# How to return this result using linq in entity framework( 2 foreign key mapping table)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a table that contains 2 foreign key that reference separately to 2 different table.
I would like to return the result of all person that has course of "Science".

How to retrieve the record back using LINQ?
This is what i gotten so far:

```
       return 
        _ctx.Person
            .Include(u => u.Course
            .Where(ug=>ug.CourseName== "Science"));
```

This is not working as it shows the error.

> The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property
>   defined on the type

```
public class Course
{
    public int CourseID {get; set;}
    public string CourseName {get; set;}

    public virtual ICollection<Person> Persons { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
   public int PersonID {get; set;}
   public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }
}
```

This is the mapping table. Only contains 2 foreign key from 2 different table.
I could not use this table inside the solution.As the code first won't generate this table as it doesn't contain it's own PK.

```
//This is not shown in the EntityFramework when generating Code First.
    public class PersonCouseMap 
    {
      public int PersonID {get; set;}
      public int CourseID {get; set;}
    }
```

> Update : this works after I switched the entity.

```
return _ctx.Course
       .Include(u=>u.Person)
       .Where(ug=>ug.CourseName == "Sciene");
```

Anyone can explain why it won't work the another way round.
I need to display a List of Person who have course of "Science",
not Course Science that has a list of user.

Comment: Looks like de relations between the tables are not defined

Comment: I have already have that relationship created by default using code first. It's just that I am struggling to write the correct LINQ.

Comment: I think your parentheses in the code are wrong. The whole `Where` clause is inside the `Include`, instead of after it.

Answer (score 2):

The original query does not work because you've pushed the `Where` predicate inside the `Include` expression, which is not supported as indicated by the exception message.

The `Include` method is EF specific extension method used to eager load related data. It has nothing to do with the query filtering.

To apply the desired filter *person that has course of "Science"* you need [`Any`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972(v=vs.110).aspx) based predicate since the `Person.Courses` is a collection:

```
return _ctx.Person
    .Where(p => p.Courses.Any(c => c.CourseName == "Science"));
```

To include the related data in the result, combine it with `Include` call(s):

```
return _ctx.Person
    .Include(p => p.Courses)
    .Where(p => p.Courses.Any(c => c.CourseName == "Science"));
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is no relations between these two entites, you can establish a relationship by making the following changes to your code:

Here I am assuming that you want to establish Many-to-Many relationship between these two tables by having a third entity **PersonCourseMap**

```
public class Course
{
    public int CourseID {get; set;}
    public string CourseName {get; set;}

   public virtual ICollection<CoursePersons> Courses { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
   public int PersonID {get; set;}
   public virtual ICollection<PersonCourse> Courses { get; set; }
}

public class PersonCourseMap 
{
  public int PersonID {get; set;}
  public int CourseID {get; set;}

  public virtual ICollection<Person> Persons { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }
}
```

After making above changes you can simply navigate through properties.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The relationship has already defined by code first entity framework. The part I struggled was to come out with the correct LINQ statement.

Answer (score 0):

Include Foreign Key Mapping

```
public class Course
{
    public int CourseID {get; set;}
    public string CourseName {get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Person> Person {get; set}
}

public class Person
{
   public int PersonID {get; set;}
   public virtual ICollection<Course> Course {get; set;}
}

using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotation.Schema;
public class PersonCouseMap 
{
   [ForeignKey("Person")]
   public int PersonID {get; set;}
   [ForeignKey("Course")]
   public int CourseID {get; set;}

   public virtual ICollection<Person> Person {get; set;}
   public virtual ICollection<Course> Course {get; set;}
}
```